# Is this edit war over?

Tags: discussion

[https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-is-wittgenstein-s-notorious-paragraph-about-the-gödels-theorem-not-obviou?rq=1](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-is-wittgenstein-s-notorious-paragraph-about-the-g%C3%B6dels-theorem-not-obviou?rq=1)

This is a really good question. I was hoping it could be unlocked so as to be engaged normally with. It would be a shame for it to remain permanently locked.

Comment: That question is not the subject of an edit war. If you look at the edits, nearly all of them were made by the author. The problem is that the author is a crackpot who misuses this site to push idiosyncratic theories of his own rather than to ask bona fide questions. He constantly edited the question to keep it bumped to the top of the stack. He has been subject to bans and restrictions on the PhilosophySE site and the MathSE site for doing this.